# How to setup a "server is down" message like Reddit and Twitter does?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, cloudflare

I have a VPS with our Ubuntu LoCo Team's blog, but I want to setup a message that says the server is down when it happens, like Reddit and Twitter does.

For example, if I restart the server or my VPS goes down, I want the user to load another page, from another server, saying the site is down and will be back soon.

I guess that can be done with redundancy, but I don't know anything about it to be honest. Is that possible and there is any tutorial about it?

I searched a lot, but since I don't know how to call this "feature", I don't really know what to look for.

Anyway, if it helps, I use Nginx, PHP-FPM, PHP-APC and Ubuntu Server 12.04. My DNS is hosted at CloudFlare Pro.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: CloudFlare already provides such a page for you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, but it I want to create my own.

Answer (score 2):

Such solutions are typically achieved through a proxy or a load balancer.

A large site like reddit doesn't serve everything from one server. There's a load balancer in the front. And when it detects that it's web servers (such as one running php-fpm) is no longer responding, it responds with an error 503.

You already have two tools that can achieve this. Cloudflare and nginx.

Cloudflare is a mix of CDN & proxy service and offers you such tool already. This will be the simplest route.

Nginx also has the ability to act like a proxy and/or load balancer and can serve custom errors depending on certain situations. Like the php-fpm not responding. However, this would obviously require you to have at least 2 independent servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. CloudFlare does offer this solution, but I want to create my own. I can create custom ones there, but it must have they brand on it, by what I saw :/

Comment: @JulianFernandes You can use nginx then as already mentioned.